# How to use PDF::API2 to merge several pdfs into one with Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, merge

I have lots of pdf documents to merge together, so I wrote this code to do it.  It works for the case where I only have two pdf documents to merge, but if I give it more than two, the extra documents come out garbled.  Can you help me find what's wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PDF::API2;
use List::Util qw( reduce );


# Given two pdfs and a page number, appends the given page of the second pdf to the first pdf
sub append_page_to_pdf {
    my ( $pdf1, $pdf2, $pg ) = @_;
    $pdf1->importpage( $pdf2, $pg );
}

# Given two pdfs, appends the second to the first.  Closes pdf2
sub merge_2_pdfs {
    my ($pdf1, $pdf2) = @_;
    map &append_page_to_pdf( $pdf1, $pdf2, $_ ), 1..$pdf2->pages;
    $pdf2->end;
    return $pdf1;
}

# does what it says
sub open_pdf {
    my $file = $_[0];
    my $pdf = PDF::API2->open( $file );
    print "Opened pdf ( $file )\n";
    return $pdf;
}

# reduces merge_2_pdfs over an array of pdfs
sub merge_pdfs {
    my @files = @_;
    my $starting_filename = shift @files;
    my $start_pdf = &open_pdf( $starting_filename );
    my $final_pdf = reduce { &merge_2_pdfs( $a, &open_pdf( $b ) ) } $start_pdf, @files;
    return $final_pdf;
}

# Get the arguments ie save_name, file1, file2, file3, ...
my @files = @ARGV;
my $save_name = shift @files;
my $save = &merge_pdfs( @files );
$save->saveas( $save_name );
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that given as an answer to a similar question on another SO thread.  The problem is that appendpdf.pl only merges two pdf documents.  I'll take a shell script that uses appendpdf.pl to do this, but it's wrong: there's needless file io (an extra read and write) which would occur for every file.

Comment: I'm the author of appendpdf.pl. It's a simple wrapper script around CAM::PDF. It's trivial to append a ton of PDFs. Just look at the appendpdf.pl source code and you'll see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem in your code is because you `shift` one of the files off before you merge them.

```
my $save_name = shift @files; 
# which should be 
my $save_name = $files[0];
```

Otherwise, the code actually works, and I didn't find anything garbled.

A few tips:

1. `use strict` and `use warnings`
2. The general practice now is to omit the `&` in your subroutine calls. [See here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) for exceptions to that rule.
3. In this case, the subroutines make your code verbose, which made it harder to follow. Here's something more concise.

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use List::Util 'reduce';
   use PDF::API2;

   my $new
     = reduce { $a->importpage($b, $_) foreach 1 .. $b->pages; $a }
       map { PDF::API2->open($_) }
       @ARGV;
   $new->saveas('new.pdf');
   ```
4. A simple loop is a little more straighforward to read than using `reduce`.

   ```
   use PDF::API2;

   my $new = PDF::API2->new;
   foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {
       my $pdf = PDF::API2->open($filename);
       $new->importpage($pdf, $_) foreach 1 .. $pdf->pages;
   }
   $new->saveas('new.pdf');
   ```

Comment: Awesome answer, man!  I have a question.  Why doesn't the return value of &merge_2_pdfs get fed into the next iteration in the original code?

Comment: I was mistaken. The return from `merge_2_pdfs()` does feed back into the next iteration. The error was somewhere else as above.

Answer (score 1):

[PDF::Reuse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PDF%3a%3aReuse).

```
prFile('myFile.pdf');
for my $pdf (@PDFS) {
    prDoc($pdf);
}
prEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is my library, [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/).

```
my $pdf1 = CAM::PDF->new($file1) or die;
my $pdf2 = CAM::PDF->new($file2) or die;
my $pdf3 = CAM::PDF->new($file3) or die;
$pdf1->appendPDF($pdf2);
$pdf1->appendPDF($pdf3);
$pdf1->cleanoutput($outfile);
```

or wrap it in a loop over @ARGV perhaps. For just two PDFs, I have a simple cmdline wrapper to do the same:

[appendpdf.pl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/bin/appendpdf.pl) file1.pdf file2.pdf out.pdf